# jQuery - method issue - unsure how to proceed

Tags: jquery

My apologies for the title name - I'm not sure how to label this one.

I'm trying to equalize the heights of a set of items I have in every row.

(Three items are shown in a row)

First.) Every row technically has 4 items.
However I'm doing an A/B Test to show the items larger 
(so 3 columns instead of 4) - thus I need to count the first 3 items of every row.

I tried breaking out of the each function using return false. only to realise that if there is 4 items per .row - it doesn't help me to go about it this way.

NOTE, the fourth item of the first row is technically the first item of the second row, and I dont know how to work around this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Ultimately breaking it somewhere because the actual row with three items now has different heights:

[Updated my code to match Alon Eitan's]
but now i'm receiving this on the LAST row:

[image]

I noticed the first row also wasn't equal heights - it's working fine - i just worry if it happens in another positions it'll break the layout.

[image]

Please see below the code I am using:

```
 <script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {

    // Select and loop the container element of the elements you want to equalise
    $('div.row').each(function(){  

var highestBox = 0;
var lastIndex = 0;
$('div.result.product').each(function(index){
    if( index > 1 && index  % 3 == 0 ) {
        $('div.result.product').slice(index, -3).height(highestBox);
        highestBox = 0;
        lastIndex = index;
    }
    if($(this).height() > highestBox) {
        highestBox = $(this).height(); 
    }
});

if( highestBox > 0 && index + 1 < $('div.result.product').length ) {
    // make sure that if the last row contain less than 3 items, that that those items will also get the same height
    $('div.result.product').slice(lastIndex).height(highestBox);
} 
    }); 
 }); 


</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you just add that to your stylesheet? `div.result.product { height: 347px;}` - Ultimately I would change the rows to 3 images rather than 4, but if you're just looking for a quickfix..

Comment: I can't because the rows vary so much in height - so I need to get the max height of the row - and set all items to that height.

Comment: Not necessarily, set each of the rows to the set height, then set the product div to max-height: with overflow:hidden, sure some will cut off but no one will know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "regroup" the items, then you need to select them all, and then you need to identify that you are iterating an element in a new row. Example:

```
var highestBox = 0;
var lastIndex = 0;
$('div.result.product').each(function(index){
    if($(this).height() > highestBox) {
        highestBox = $(this).outerHeight(); 
    }

    if( index > 1 && index  % 3 == 0 ) {
        $('div.result.product').slice(index-3, index).outerHeight(highestBox);
        highestBox = 0;
        lastIndex = index;
    }
});

if( highestBox > 0 && lastIndex + 1 < $('div.result.product').length ) {
    // make sure that if the last row contain less than 3 items, that that those items will also get the same height
    $('div.result.product').slice(lastIndex).outerHeight(highestBox);
}
```

Comment: Oh wow @AlonEitan we're REALLY close - I'm updating my question to show you what's happening now. Thank you.

Comment: @MikeVanStan Try now please

Comment: I'm injecting it onto the page - it's not actually in the source code.

Comment: I updated the code - but it's cutting off the height in the 5th, 6th and 7th rows.

Comment: I have cahnged it to `outerHeight` so it will include the padding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111460/discussion-between-mike-van-stan-and-alon-eitan).

Comment: @MikeVanStan Unfortunately I have to go now, i'll be back in a few hours. You can update the question if you want with the current state and the problem you're having with it and i'll investigate when  i'm back (or maybe someone else before me)

Comment: Sounds great! thank you for all your time and effort - I'll try work on it in your absense!